# why does Ubuntu downloads apps from 93.184.215.223?

Tags: 12.04, apt, repository, canonical, official-repositories

Does anyone know I why my ubuntu machine makes a connection to 93.184.215.223 when I use apt-get? I thought all the software repositories were at *.canonical.com. I haven't added any 3rd party repositories.......

Comment: You download from the sources you've configured it to download from. It's the *mirror* you've selected... So, what mirror are you on? See the Sofware Sources in the System Updates application. You'll also see a partner repository and some PPAs you might have enabled. If you're asking about connections to some other servers used for the Software Centre, see [Which port does Ubuntu Software Center use?](http://askubuntu.com/a/250275/88802) (also covers hosts)

Comment: @gertvdijk Thanks. Where are the mirrors listed in the **Software Sources**? **Download from:** says Server for United States

Answer (score 4):

Not all the repositories are at canonical.com. According to [the mirror list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors), the UK has 18 mirrors, including Canonical. All in all, there are over 300 mirrors throughout the globe. To find out which one you connect to, look at the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 0):

if youre familiar with synaptic package manager, go in settings >> repositories, which allows you to choose what to download and from where.
(your ip adress 93.184... is located in california lol)