# Where can I find a list of ports for update to give to our ISP so that we can update Ubuntu Server 18.04?

Tags: networking, 18.04, package-management

Original title: Не могу обновить или установить пакеты Ubuntu server 18.04

Can't update or install packages on Ubuntu server 18.04. Internet provider Rostelecom, we sit behind their proxy server and content filtering. And so that we could work normally with Ubuntu server 18.04, they ask us to provide update ports. `sources.list` is not enough for them. Where can I see the list of ports??? Thank you in advance! Regards, Oleg.

Comment: Пожалуйста, пиши по-английски. Спасибо.

Comment: @mchid Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your sources list file should show mostly http and maybe one or two https addresses.

These are ports 80 and 443 respectively.

￰http￰ ￰ ￰ ￰ =￰ ￰ port 80

https￰￰ ￰ =￰ ￰ port 443

DNS requests are also sent over port 53 (UDP).

Let your ISP know that these are the ports in use and to please stop filtering content to and from those addresses.

[Also, see this answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049765/167115).